# How can I get my Java arithmetic and print statements to work properly?

Tags: java, math, printing, printf

I'm new to Java and after working on my second assignment with the language for a while I've gotten the code to where it will run. The assignment involves creating 2 separate classes that allow a user to create 2 different order inquiries. The problem I'm having is that when I go to run my code the operations I set up to find the shipping fee and total are not working, and the console is not displaying the following print statement either. Here is my build result:

```
Enter the customer name for the first order: 
John
Enter the item ID for the first order: 
1845ADG
Enter the customer name for the second order: 
Jane
Enter the item ID for the second order: 
6842DEZ
Enter the price of the item for the first customer's order: 
51.02
Enter the quantity of items ordered by the first customer: 
5
Enter the price of the item for the second customer's order: 
62.03
Enter the quantity of items ordered by the second customer: 
6
Here's the data you entered for the first order:
Customer Name: John
Item ID: 1845ADG
Item Price: $51.02
Quantity: 5
Subtotal: $255.10
Shipping Fee: $0.00
Total: $0.00
0
Would you like to make any changes to the item price or quantity? Enter 0 for no or 1 for yes.%nNo changes made.
Here's the data you entered for the second order:
Customer Name: Jane
Item ID: 6842DEZ
Item Price: $62.03
Quantity: 6
Subtotal: $372.18
Shipping Fee: $0.00
Total: $0.00
1
Would you like to make any changes to the item price or quantity? Enter 0 for no or 1 for yes.Enter the correct item price for the second customer's order: 
12.03
Enter the correct quantity order for the second order: 
6

Here's the updated data you entered for the second order:
Customer Name: Jane
Item ID: 6842DEZ
Item Price: $12.03
Quantity: 6
Subtotal: $72.18
Shipping Fee: $0.00
Total: $0.00
------------------------------------------------------------------------
BUILD SUCCESS
------------------------------------------------------------------------
Total time:  01:11 min
Finished at: 2021-03-15T13:16:14-04:00
------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I'm a bit confused as to why these values are coming up as zero. In my data class I have my setSubtotal() function set up in the same way as the setShippingFee() and setTotalOrderPrice() functions, but the subtotal function is working properly whereas the other two are not. I have both the subtotal and shippingFee values initialized to 0 in my application class, so I don't think that is the issue but I will include it as well. Here is the relevant code from the data class:

```
    public void setSubtotal (double itemPrice, int quantity) {
        subtotal = itemPrice * quantity;
        this.subtotal = subtotal;
    }
    
    public double getSubtotal() {
        return subtotal;
    }
    
    public void setShippingFee(double subtotal) {
            shippingFee = subtotal * 0.1;
            this.shippingFee = shippingFee;
    }

    public double getShippingFee() {
        return shippingFee;
    }
    
    public void setTotalOrderPrice(double subtotal, double shippingFee) {
        totalOrderPrice = subtotal + shippingFee;
        this.totalOrderPrice = totalOrderPrice;

    }
    
    public double getTotalOrderPrice() {
        return totalOrderPrice;
    }
}
```

And the application class:

```
double subtotal = 0, shippingFee = 0;
```

As well as the shipping fee and total not working properly, the program also is not displaying the line after the "Total" line in each order (which is supposed to ask the user to input a 0/1 depending on whether or not they wish to change the item price or quantity for the order) even though the printf statement includes the entire order as well as that line. Lastly, the program is supposed to display all of the information its collected after any changes have been made, but that is not happening either. Here is the code pertaining to the print statements in my application class:

```
        System.out.printf("Here's the data you entered for the first order:%nCustomer Name: %s%nItem ID: %s%n"
                + "Item Price: $%.2f%nQuantity: %d%nSubtotal: $%.2f%nShipping Fee: $%.2f%nTotal: $%.2f%nWould you like to make any changes to the item price or quantity? Enter 0 for no or 1 for yes."
                , order1.getCustomerName(), order1.getItemID(), order1.getItemPrice(), order1.getQuantity(),order1.getSubtotal(), order1.getShippingFee(), order1.getTotalOrderPrice());
        int selection1 = input.nextInt();
        if (selection1 == 0) {
            System.out.printf("%nNo changes made.");
        }
        else if (selection1 == 1) {
                System.out.println("Enter the correct item price for the first customer's order: ");
                    itemPrice = input.nextDouble();
                    order1.setItemPrice(itemPrice);
                System.out.println("Enter the correct quantity order for the first order: ");
                    quantity = input.nextInt();
                    order1.setQuantity(quantity);
                order1.setSubtotal(itemPrice, quantity);
                order1.setShippingFee(subtotal);
                order1.setTotalOrderPrice(subtotal, shippingFee);
                System.out.printf("%nHere's the updated data you entered for the first order:%nCustomer Name: %s%nItem ID: %s%n"
                        + "Item Price: $%.2f%nQuantity: %d%nSubtotal: $%.2f%nShipping Fee: $%.2f%nTotal: $%.2f",
                        order1.getCustomerName(), order1.getItemID(), order1.getItemPrice(), order1.getQuantity(),order1.getSubtotal(), order1.getShippingFee(), order1.getTotalOrderPrice());
```

(The code for the second order I just copied and pasted and updated the 1's to 2's and first's to second's)

```
System.out.printf("Here's all of the data that you have entered:%n%nOrder 1:%nCustomer Name: %s%nItem ID: %s%n"
                 + "Item Price: $%.2f%nQuantity: %d%nSubtotal: $%.2f%nShipping Fee: $%.2f%nTotal: $%.2f%n%n"
                 + "Order 2:%nCustomer Name: %s%nItem ID: %s%nItem Price: $%.2f%nQuantity: %d%n"
                 + "Subtotal: $%.2f%nShipping Fee: $%.2f%nTotal: $%.2f%n", 
                 order1.getCustomerName(), order1.getItemID(), order1.getItemPrice(), order1.getQuantity(), order1.getSubtotal(), order1.getShippingFee(), order1.getTotalOrderPrice(), order2.getCustomerName(), order2.getItemID(), order2.getItemPrice(), order2.getQuantity(), order2.getSubtotal(), order2.getShippingFee(), order2.getTotalOrderPrice());
```

I'm not sure what to do, as I've tried separating the print statements, removing the initialization, and just restarting my computer but it still won't work properly. Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 0):

```
order1.setSubtotal(itemPrice, quantity);
order1.setShippingFee(order1.getSubtotal());
order1.setTotalOrderPrice(order1.getSubtotal(), order1.getShippingFee());
```

The `subtotal` and `shippingFee` fields you have in your Application class are not the same as the fields with the same name in the Order class. With setters, you only change the fields in the Order class, and you need your getters to fetch them.